# In Hebrews 13:3 is the author referring to a particular group?

Tags: hebrews, referent-identification

KJV Hebrews 13 : 3

> Remember them that are in bonds, as bound with them; and them which suffer adversity, as being yourselves also in the body.

In the above text we are encouraged to remember/pray for those who are in bonds/prisons.

It's not clear whether the author has a particular group of people or just for all who are in prisons

Is there a particular group the author was referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very specific answer is impossible from the text without more information. However, we can at least go so far as to say the author is not thinking of common criminals but of those who have been imprisoned for their faith. [Barnes](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/hebrews/13-3.htm), for example, says:

> *Remember them that are in bonds*,.... Not for criminal actions, or for debt, though such should be remembered, and pity showed them,
> especially the latter; but such as are in bonds for the sake of
> Christ, and the Gospel. This has been often the lot of God's people,
> who should be remembered, by praying for them, sending comfortable
> letters to them, personally visiting them, and relieving them under
> their distresses.

Hebrews ch. 10 provides additional insight into the OP question:

> Recall the former days when, after you were enlightened, you endured a
> hard struggle with sufferings, sometimes being publicly exposed to
> abuse and affliction, and sometimes being partners with those so
> treated. For you had compassion on the prisoners, and you joyfully
> accepted the plundering of your property, since you knew that you
> yourselves had a better possession and an abiding one. (32-34)

Apparently some of those in the congregation/s to whom Hebrews was addressed were still suffering, as the final chapter begins with the admonition cited in the OP, to visit those in prison. **We may conclude that the author refers specifically those who were imprisoned for their faith.**

Answer (score 1):

Here is my very literal rendering of Heb 13:3 -

> Remember those prisoners as if you were bound with [them], and those
> being mistreated as you yourselves [were suffering] in the body.

This verse is rendered more idiomatically by most modern versions as:

- NIV: Continue to remember those in prison as if you were together with them in prison, and those who are mistreated as if you yourselves were suffering.
- NLT: Remember those in prison, as if you were there yourself. Remember also those being mistreated, as if you felt their pain in your own bodies.
- ERV: Remember those who are in prison, as though in prison with them, and those who are mistreated, since you also are in the body.
- BSB: Remember those in prison as if you were bound with them, and those who are mistreated as if you were suffering with them.
- NASB: Remember the prisoners, as though in prison with them, and those who are badly treated, since you yourselves also are in the body.

It is not completely clear if the author of Hebrews is referring only to prisoners who were imprisoned because of their faith or prisoners more generally.  Both are very likely.  Therefore, in the absence of more specific information, I am inclined to the latter without neglecting the former.

Ellicott offers these comments:

> (3) **As bound with them.—Either** (1) “As if ye yourselves were in
> bonds” (see Hebrews 10:33-34; 1Corinthians 12:26)—by true
> fellow-feeling make yourselves sharers in their lot; or, (2) “mindful
> that ye too are in bonds”—like them ye are Christ’s prisoners, and
> their bonds are but one of the tokens of that service in which all
> Christians are bound. (Comp. 1Corinthians 7:22.)
>
> **As being yourselves also in the body**.—“Mindful that you, like them, still dwell in a body liable to pain, and may therefore suffer
> ill-treatment in the cause of Christ.”

Benson is slightly different

> Hebrews 13:3. Remember — In your prayers and by your help; them that
> are in bonds — Thrown into prison for the sake of Christ, as if you
> yourselves were bound with them — Seeing ye are members one of
> another; and them which suffer adversity — Των κακουχουμενων, who are
> ill-treated, or afflicted with evil; as being yourselves also in the
> body — And consequently liable to similar sufferings.

Barnes is similar to Ellicott -

> **Remember them that are in bonds** - All who are "bound;" whether prisoners of war; captives in dungeons; those detained in custody for
> trial; those who are imprisoned for righteousness' sake, or those held
> in slavery. The word used here will include all instances where
> "bonds, shackles, chains were ever used." Perhaps there is an
> immediate allusion to their fellow-Christians who were suffering
> imprisonment on account of their religion, of whom there were
> doubtless many at that time, but the "principle" will apply to every
> case of those who are imprisoned or oppressed. The word "remember"
> implies more than that we are merely to "think" of them; compare
> Exodus 20:8; Ecclesiastes 12:1. It means that we are to remember them
> "with appropriate sympathy;" or as we should wish others to remember
> us if we were in their circumstances.